# Haskell equation solving in the real numbers

Tags: haskell, math, list-comprehension, precision, equation-solving

I've just started playing with GHCi. I see that list generators basically solve an equation within a given set:

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [1..20], x^2 == 4]
[2]
```

(finds only one root, as expected)

Now, why can't I solve equations with results in ℝ, given that the solution *is* included in the specified range?

```
[x | x <- [0.1,0.2..2.0], x*4 == 2]
```

How can I solve such equations within real numbers set?

Edit: Sorry, I meant `0.1`, of course.

Comment: Ah, by 'R' you mean the real numbers, not the language R! Unfortunately, there is no way to generate the set of all the members of R in between two numbers (or all the floats), which would be an incredibly large set.

Comment: @Andrew... more than incredibly large :-) let's not hide him the Truth any longer: there are **infinite** Real values between 0.001 and 0.01. Infinite. More than the ridiculously litte huge-number of particles that a sealed universe could ever contain. :)

Comment: Worth noting: list comprehensions like the simple one you have given can be written simply as `filter ((==2).(*4)) xs`

Comment: @Stephane... I meant that there is an incredibly large (but finite) number of representable floating-point numbers between 0 and 2 of a particular size (e.g., 64-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this is not an efficient way to solve equations, but it can be done with ratios.

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Ratio 
Prelude Data.Ratio> [x|x<-[1%10, 2%10..2], x*4 == 2]
[1 % 2]
```

Read `x % y` as `x divided by y`.

Answer (score 8):

List comprehension doesn't *solve equations*, it just generates a list of items that belong to certain sets. If your set is defined as *any `x` in `[1..20]` such that `x^2==4`*, that's what you get.

You cannot do that with a complete list of any real number from `0.01` to `2.0`, because such real list cannot be represented in haskell (or better: it cannot be represented on any computer), since it has infinite numbers with infinite precision.

`[0.01,0.2..2.0]` is a list made of the following numbers:

```
Prelude> [0.01,0.2..2.0]
[1.0e-2,0.2,0.39,0.5800000000000001,0.7700000000000001,0.9600000000000002,1.1500000000000004,1.3400000000000005,1.5300000000000007,1.7200000000000009,1.910000000000001]
```

And none of these numbers satisfies your condution.

---

Note that you probably meant `[0.1,0.2..2.0]` instead of `[0.01,0.2..2.0]`. Still:

```
Prelude> [0.1,0.2..2.0]
[0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4000000000000001,0.5000000000000001,0.6000000000000001,0.7000000000000001,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2000000000000002,1.3000000000000003,1.4000000000000004,1.5000000000000004,1.6000000000000005,1.7000000000000006,1.8000000000000007,1.9000000000000008,2.000000000000001]
```

Comment: And even if you could generate a list of all the floating-point representations between 0 and 2, this would be an incredibly inefficient way to "solve" the equation, as it just searches one by one from the beginning to the end.

Comment: You could try to fix the type to `Rational` instead.

Comment: @Andrew Jaffe, further, a solution may not even exist in the floating point numbers.  `(sqrt 2)^2 == 2  --->  False`.

Answer (score 4):

The floating point issue can be solved in this way:

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [0.1, 0.2 .. 2.0], abs(2 - x*4) < 1e-9]
[0.5000000000000001]
```

For a reference why floating point numbers can make problems see this: [Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)

Comment: This does work for the specific example, but a fixed epsilon of 10⁻⁹ really isn't very reliable, because floating-point inaccuracy isn't absolute. (If the numbers get too small, you may get a whole cloud of false positives, if they are too big again none may satisfy.) To solve equations with floating-point numbers, one should either use a proper solver (Newton-Raphson) or at least compare the _relative_ deviations.

Answer (score 3):

<s>First of all `[0.01,0.2..2.0]` wouldn't include 0.5 even if floating point arithmetic were accurate. I assume you meant the first element to be `0.1`.</s>

The list `[0.1,0.2..2.0]` does not contain 0.5 because floating point arithmetic is imprecise and the 5th element of `[0.1,0.2..2.0]` is `0.5000000000000001`, not 0.5.