# Haskell: Unexpected output for expression [0, 0.1 .. 1]

Tags: haskell, floating-point, range-notation

When evaluating the expression:

```
*main> [0, 0.1 .. 1]
```

I was actually expecting:

```
 [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
```

But I was quite shocked to see the output be

```
[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4000000000000001,0.5000000000000001,0.6000000000000001,0.7000000000000001,0.8,0.9,1.0]
```

***Why does Haskell produce that result upon evaluation?***

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does ghci say that 1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 > 3.3 is True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038647/why-does-ghci-say-that-1-1-1-1-1-1-3-3-is-true)

Comment: @TomMD, @Avilo: Thanks for the clarification guys but I also meant that it seems a bit weird that for example 0.3....0004 and .5, .6, .7 all end in 0001 while .2, .8 and .9 are "round". It just doesn't seem consistent imprecision, i don't know if am explaining myself.

Comment: @carlos When you learn how floating point is represented this will make perfect sense.  Notice accurate values are sums of two to a negative power.

Comment: @TomMD. Thanks buddy ill add that to the list.

Comment: [Different question, similar answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983985/haskell-equation-solving-in-the-real-numbers/)

Comment: @TomMD: two to a negative power?  You mean like 0.5?

Comment: Definitely check out "What Every [Programmer](http://floating-point-gui.de)/[Computer Scientist](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5836/What-Every-Computer-Scientist-Should-Know-About-FloatingPoint-Arithmetic) Should Know about Floating Point Arithmetic."

Comment: @luqui `0.5` represents fine, it has error in Carlos's code due to starting from some approximate value (~ `0.4`) and adding `0.1`.  If you're just testing single values then using the below C program is probably best as it avoids rounding before printing (I think `.17%f` is sufficient for that).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a result of the imprecision of [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) values, it isn't particular to Haskell.  If you can't deal with the approximation inherent in floating point then you can use [Rational](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aRational) at a high performance cost:

```
> import Data.Ratio
Data.Ratio> [0,1%10.. 1%1]
[0 % 1,1 % 10,1 % 5,3 % 10,2 % 5,1 % 2,3 % 5,7 % 10,4 % 5,9 % 10,1 % 1]
```

Just to hammer the point home, here's Python:

```
>>> 0.3
0.29999999999999999
```

And here's C:

```
void main() { printf("%0.17f\n",0.3); }

$ gcc t.c 2>/dev/null ; ./a.out
0.29999999999999999
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038647/why-does-ghci-say-that-1-1-1-1-1-1-3-3-is-true).  As it states, floating point numbers aren't precise in the CPU.