# Haskell returning incorrect result

Tags: haskell, double, ghci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell: Unexpected output for expression [0, 0.1 .. 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048920/haskell-unexpected-output-for-expression-0-0-1-1)

In Haskell, does anyone know the reason for the following result?

```
Prelude Data.List> map (\x -> x - 0.1) [0.2,0.3..0.9]

[0.1,0.19999999999999998,0.29999999999999993,0.3999999999999999,0.4999999999999999,0.5999999999999998,0.6999999999999996,0.7999999999999995]
```

Instead of

```
[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]
```

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de for the reason, and maybe `Data.Ratio` to the rescue.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko is correct. Just to remind that almost all data is represented using binary form and thus exponent of floatings is not 10^e (not decimal point), but 2^e (bit point) and thus 0.3 and 0.1 is actually represented by something similar to `153*2^^(-9)` (1.0011001B*2^(-2) which is slightly less that `0.3`) and `205*2^^(-11)` (1.1001101B*2^(-2) with mantissa rounded from 1.100110011B and thus it slightly bigger than `0.1`). I used [this online tool to see representation](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `Double` (an imprecise but efficient data type) will be chosen for fractional data. If you annotate it to use `Rational` instead, then you can get precise answers.

```
ghci> map (\x -> x - 0.1) [0.2,0.3..0.9] :: [Rational]
[1 % 10,1 % 5,3 % 10,2 % 5,1 % 2,3 % 5,7 % 10,4 % 5]
```

The percent sign is used to indicate precise fractions, so `1 % 10` means one tenth.